# Unable to create an xml file with a child element inside a child element using C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I wish to create an xml file with "Package" as the root node, "types" being its child node and further "members" being the child node of "types". Another "name" node which will be a sibiling node of "members" node.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Package"));

            foreach (var group in componentsGroupedByType)
            {
                 doc.Root.Add(new XElement("types"));

                    foreach (var user in group)
                    {
                        doc.Root.Add(new XElement("members", user.Item2));
                    }
                 doc.Root.Add(new XElement("name", group.Key));
            }
```

Expected Output:

```
<Package>
   <types>
     <members>xyz</members>
     <members>xyz</members>
     <name>abc</name>
   </types>

   <types>
     <members>xyz</members>
     <members>xyz</members>
     <name>abc</name>
   </types>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<members>` and `<name>` elements should be added to the `<types>` element you created, not the document root.

Do this instead:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Package",
        from g in componentsGroupedByType
        select new XElement("types",
            from u in g
            select new XElement("members", u.Item2),
            new XElement("name", u.Key)
        )
    )
);
```